# get date and month from html5 datefield javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `date` field which looks like this

```js
var date_input = document.getElementById('date_cust');
  date_input.onchange = function(){
  alert("The date you selected is : "+date_input.value);
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" type="date" class="form-control" id="date_cust" name="date_cust" required />
```

and resulted/alerted something like this:

```
``The date you selected is: 2020-01-20``
```

I want to know is there any ways to get only the date and the month, because I want to compare the date and the month with the date and the month which I already set, for example, 31st of March (31-03 / 03-31). Something like this.

```
var 31march = '03-31';
if (extracted_data == 31march) {
  alert("Happy Birthday");
} else { 
  alert("Not your birthday yet.")
}
```

I already tried to parse the value like this:

```
var date_input = Date.parse(document.getElementById('date_cust').innerHTML);
```

but it resulted in `NaN`

is there any other ways for this case? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @kank95 did you get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the date and get the parts that you need

```
var dateArr = date_input.value.split("-");
console.log('year: ' + dateArr[0])
console.log'month: ' + (dateArr[1])
console.log('day: ' + dateArr[2])

var new_date = dateArr[2] + '-' + dateArr[1];
console.log(new_date)
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer,precisely solve my case to extract the date and the month

Answer (score 2):

Use `getMonth()` from `new Date()`:

```
const myDate = new Date('2020-01-30')
console.log(myDate.getMonth())

//0 = january
//1 = February
...
```

[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: I think the OP is looking also for the way to correctly extract the date from the `input` element.

Comment: yes i'm looking how to extract date and month from date field not static value, but hey thanks for the answer

Comment: I know you want to extract from the field value, you just need to pass `document.getElementById('date_cust').value` as parameter for `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

To get the date from the `input` element, you must use the `new Date()` method passing the `value` attribute of the `input` as param.

```
 var dateCustom = new Date(this.value);
```

`this` refers to the `input` element because you will use in the event handler.

Then, use the [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) JS methods to extract the day of the month and the month.

```js
var date_input = document.getElementById('date_cust');
  date_input.onchange = function(){
    var dateCustom = new Date(this.value);
    document.getElementById('day').textContent = dateCustom.getDate();
    document.getElementById('month').textContent = dateCustom.getMonth() + 1;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" type="date" class="form-control" id="date_cust" name="date_cust" required />

<p id="day"></p>
<p id="month"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

> *getDate()*

```
   const yourDate = new Date('2019-03-10');

   console.log(yourDate.getDate())

    console.log(yourDate)
```

**variable in js can't be start with a number "var 31march = '03-31';"
should be for example var march31 = '03-31' ;
**

these are the set of rules you should consider:

1-Names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs.

2-Names must begin with a letter

3-Names can also begin with $ and _ (but we will not use it in this tutorial)

4-Names are case sensitive (y and Y are different variables)

Reserved words (like JavaScript keywords) cannot be used as names

Comment: Please note that `getDay()` returns the day of the week. The OP want to extract the day of the month; you use `getDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since parsing of even the formats specified in ECMA-262 is not consistent, it is recommended to never rely on the built–in parser and to always manually parse strings, say using a library and provide the format to the parser.

E.g. in moment.js you might write:

```
let m = moment(date_input.value).format('MM-DD');
```

Where:

- **MM** stands for month number (eg: 01-12)
- **DD** stands for day of the month (eg: 01-31)

Read the moment docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/

More information about why it is giving you a **NaN** as result can be found here: [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that might work for you:

```js
var date_input = document.getElementById('date_cust');
  date_input.onchange = function() {  
  var birthday = '3-31';
  let dateSelected = new Date(date_input.value);    
  let dateMonth = (dateSelected.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + dateSelected.getDate() ;    
  if (dateMonth === birthday) {
    alert("Happy Birthday");
  } else {
    alert("Not your birthday yet.")
  } 
}
```

but it is better to split the date input value by `-` so that you know first value is the year, and the second one is a month and third one is a year.

Here is my code pen link: https://codepen.io/gideonbabu/pen/ZEYdzLj

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, i tried this too and works as well but i prefer the answer from KoKa